# Why doesn't killall work from script?

Tags: embedded-linux, busybox

I have a script (runcx) that starts two programs (cxLog and cx). I wish to be able to kill the whole mess, so I created a script:

```
50:/root # cat stop
killall runcx
killall cx
killall cxLog
```

But it doesn't work:

```
50:/root # ./stop
: no process killed
: no process killed
: no process killed
```

whereas individual commands do:

```
50:/root # killall runcx
50:/root # killall cx
killall: Could not kill pid '256': No such process
50:/root #
```

(cx is using threads, and pid '256' apparently disappeared when its parent process was killed)

What's going on here? How can I get my programs killed without all the typing?
The environment is Linux kernel 2.4.26 and a rather old version of busybox.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out after typing all the above but before hitting the post button. I had created script "stop" on a PC using vim, and the default file format is dos. Thus, killall was trying to kill programs named "runcx^M", "cx^M", and "cxLog^M". I removed the ^Ms and the script worked much better!

Comment: Just so you know, the Unix commands `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` will convert ASCII files between Unix and Windows formats, saving you the hassle of doing it manually.